# How to get into Apple BASIC prompt on an Apple IIc?

Tags: apple-ii, boot, floppy-drive

I just picked up a used Apple IIc. For some reason all I get when I boot is `Check Disk Drive` on the screen, even with a bootable disk in the internal drive:

[image: display showing "check disk drive"]

I cannot even get the system to read the external drive when powering on, so I assume I will have to tell the system to boot from the external drive once booting into BASIC.

Does anyone know how I might boot into BASIC and what command I need to run to load software from the external floppy drive?

Comment: I think you might have a hardware problem with the disk controller, but regardless, try LeftApple-Reset (i think).  That should drop you at the Basic prompt, no disk required.

Comment: Try a ProDOS (must be ProDOS!) disk in the external drive. Depending on ROM revision, it can boot from that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Press: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Reset</kbd>

This should get you to the Applesoft BASIC prompt, with a checkerboard cursor:

```
]▩
```

If you don't see that then something is wrong. Otherwise you can check your ROM version:

```
]?PEEK(64447)
255

]▩
```

ROM version 255 can supposedly boot the external drive (though I've never tried this personally) but some disks might not boot correctly. You can try with:

```
]PR#7
```

ROM versions 0, 3, and 4 need to boot the internal drive first (as PR#7 does something else) then the external drive can be accessed as drive 2.

```
]CATALOG,D2
```

Comment: Thanks. Mine is ROM version 255. I was able to get into BASIC just fine.

Answer (score 4):

Simply press <kbd>RESET</kbd> (depending on model and setting you might have to hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> or <kbd>Open-Apple</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd> before pressing <kbd>RESET</kbd>).

This will bring you into default APPLESOFT BASIC.

Just, BASIC does not contain any disk commands - unless DOS is loaded from floppy - which pressing Reset will abort :)

The only function available is to boot from a controller by typung <kbd>P</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>#</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>RETURN</kbd> - which I'd assume won't work either.

Comment: Since it is a //c, you would do Control-Reset. Reset by itself was only supported on the ][ and ][+ machines if you disabled the Control requirement (toggle switch inside the case on the keyboard PCB). Using Open-Apple plus Ctrl-Reset wouldn't bring him to BASIC since it would instead cause a cold boot of the machine.